# clickhouse remote connection issue

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have a clickhouse server running in my local network. I could access it through 192.168.0.96:9000 on the other machines in the same network.
However, after I forwarded the port 9000, and try to access outside the local network using (my IP) xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000, I got a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I couldn't figure out the issue.

The version I use is: 20.12.4.5, and
I already changed the etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml:

```
    <!-- <listen_host>::</listen_host> -->
    <!-- Same for hosts with disabled ipv6: -->
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
```

and the server does not have any firewall.

Comment: the problem is not in CH. Try to debug your forwarding using `nc` , `nc -l someport` allows to listen port.

Comment: @DennyCrane I tried to forward other ports like 5432 to 9000 and 8006 to 9000, they all worked fine.

Comment: can you show the output of `curl  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000` . Where did you get the error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT ?

Comment: @DennyCrane I got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when typing the address in Chrome.  ```curl 101.228.191.118:9000```.  
```curl: (7) Failed to connect to 101.228.191.118 port 9000: Operation timed out```

Comment: the issue is not in CH. CH cannot drop packets and produce this behaivor

Comment: I would think this as well. But I tried different ways to debug this and could figure out where is the problem. So I post here and see if anyone get similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I scanned ip you provided with `nmap` and it looks like you have only port 8888 open.
Maybe you didn't configure port forwarding properly.